# Python ImportError: failed to import from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I'm trying to compile the [MAVProxy](https://github.com/tridge/MAVProxy),

running

`python mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyUSB0 --baudrate=57600`

return an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "mavproxy.py", line 1151, in
>
> mpstate = MPState()
>
> File "mavproxy.py", line 114, in init
>
> from MAVProxy.modules.lib.mp_settings import MPSettings, MPSetting
>
> ImportError: cannot import name MPSetting

1. There is a __ init__.py
2. The directory architecture is

> MAVProxy\
>
> |-  __ init__.py
>
> |-  mavproxy.py
>
> |-  (other files
>
> |-  modules\
>
> ```
>    |- __ init__.py
>
>    |- (other files
>
>    |- lib\
>
>        |- __ init__.py
>
>        |- mp_settings.py
> ```

In the mavproxy.py

```
class MPState(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.console = textconsole.SimpleConsole()
        self.map = None
        self.map_functions = {}
        self.vehicle_type = None
        self.vehicle_name = None
        from MAVProxy.modules.lib.mp_settings import MPSettings, MPSetting
        self.settings = MPSettings(
        ....
```

In the mp_settings.py:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

class MPSetting:                                                            
    ....
class MPSettings(object):
    ....
```

Only MPSetting in mp_settings.py cannot be imported,
MPSettings can be imported successfully.

I tried to move the import code from inside class to the top of program, but still got the same error:

> ImportError: cannot import name MPSetting

any suggestion what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

1. `mp_settings.py` can have an attribute `__all__`. Maybe you need to include `MPSetting` there.
2. Do you have circular imports? Try to import all important stuff in the beginning of the file.
3. Maybe the class is removed in the module?

Comment: thanks, I added the `__all__ = [MPSetting,MPSettings]` in `mp_settings.py` and put the `import` to the beginning of `mavproxy.py` but still the same error. And if I use `from MAVProxy.modules.lib.mp_settings import *` the error become `NameError: global name 'MPSetting' is not defined`. I think it should be the same problem that MPSetting is not included. And how could I check if the class is removed in the module? sorry that I'm a newbie of python.

Comment: thanks, problem solved. there is another file `setup.py` I didn't notice, I need to run it first to build the running environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue with mavproxy.py if i do not execute with sudo.

executing with this alleviates the error: `sudo mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyUSB0 --baudrate=57600`

I have it running on an RPI3 and installed it following the instructions here: http://ardupilot.github.io/MAVProxy/html/getting_started/mavbridge.html